# How to authenticate a user over network in Android App without replicating data on Local Device?

Tags: java, android, authentication, networking

I want to know the way to query a **database to authenticate a user over network**. I am not asking for any algorithm which is described in the posts like this [Handling Password Authentication over a Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595835/handling-password-authentication-over-a-network).

I have also taken a look at [sync-adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) in android but I need authentication to be successful over the network before going ahead to Sync.

**Here I explain it. I want to do so to avoid this problem.**

I do not want a user to replicate GBs of data from server first and then authenticate in application db. I just that user will be authenticated over the network and then the data relevant to him only will be replicated(*filtered replication*)/synced on his device. So while authentication no data will be available on local device database.

Comment: over the network?? with the server i guess, you will send id and password to the server and in return server will authenticate.

Comment: Yes, but how. Using Rest API Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, What you can do is by using rest api there are few good libs avail for android.

Use those to send auth request and once it is authenticated on the server return true.

Once this done you query the server to get user data, then once you retrieve correct data form the server store it to your database, once stored get the the timestamp or the time and save it to ur database, and for the next time use this for query server if there are new record created in the server after this time stamp the return data or return nothing. so this will save your extra work.

Rather i would suggest you to implement google cloud messaging server on the server to notify.

Form more detailed architecture refer this tutorial :

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html

Comment: I am already exploring SyncAdapters and CloudSync but before doing so I need to Authenticate. Same problem again.

Comment: if you have oAuth 2 then go for this : http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html or user rest libs to send request to server and get authentication done